# What happens if choose disable OID on tables?

Tags: postgresql

When migration db from postgres 9 to 13 i have problem, latest releases not support OID, so, what is happen if choose disable OID on table properties?

Comment: i think [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) would be a better solution for your specific needs

Comment: What problem do you have? And what happend when you did a test?

Comment: @FrankHeikens, I turned off the KIDs and so far everything is fine, I still don't understand what it is for